# Why is account ownership verification required for direct debits in Spain, but not in Germany?

Tags: germany, security, spain, direct-debit

Recently, I have learned that in Spain, it is customary when indicating a bank account number for a direct debit payment<sup>1</sup> to also submit a "certificado de titularidad bancaria", a document issued by the bank that confirms you are the owner of the specified account.

Here is an anonymized example:

[image: Certificado de Titularidad]

As can be seen, it contains really no information other than linking the account number (in IBAN format) to a name and an account opening date.

This appears to be done for security reasons. I think I see the possible benefit - it makes it harder for you to indicate someone else's account number.

On the other hand, I have never heard of such a procedure (or even the document) in Germany, where I live. None of my German banks seem to offer such a document in their online menus.

This makes me wonder: **Is there any particular difference between the banking systems of Spain and Germany that makes this additional verification of account ownership necessary in Spain, but irrelevant in Germany?** Or is this only another case of "different regional traditions and inertia"?

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, the purpose of my question is not so much "What German document will a Spanish bank accept?", and more along the lines of "Is my account at a German bank less secure in this particular aspect than a Spanish account, or is the difference somehow compensated for by other differences in the banking system?"

---

<sup>1</sup>: The term was not used, but the situations as described to me sounded like that - they usually revolved around payments done by providing one's account number to the vendor.

Comment: Germany and Spain are different countries with different laws, so there's undoubtedly differences between their banking systems. It could be that there's such a legal requirement in Spain, and you should probably check with the Spanish bank with regards to what documentation they'd accept from a foreign bank in lieu of the *certificado de titularidad bancaria*

Comment: @littleadv: Sure they are different countries. At the same time, as far as I understand, both Germany and Spain participate in SEPA and use e.g. the same format of IBAN (+ BIC) to identify a bank account. The purpose of my question is not so much "What German document will a Spanish bank accept?", and more along the lines of "Is my account at a German bank less secure in this particular aspect than a Spanish account, or is the difference somehow compensated for by other differences in the banking system?"

Comment: If someone sets up a direct debit against your account without your consent, the bank is legally obligated to refund you. So in reality it’s the bank taking a risk by accepting direct debits without proper evidence.

Comment: I looked this up on a few Spanish banks (with the help of Google translate) and the main use seems to be proof of liquidity - essentially similar to a "Schufa-Auskunft" in Germany.  So it is probably less about security for you, and more a way for the vendors to make sure that you can actually pay.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: How can it be proof of liquidity if it can be obtained irrespective of the amount to be paid, and if the document itself does not make any statement about the balance on the account? Or are you saying the bank(ing website) will refuse to issue the document unless there is a certain "commonly accepted minimum amount" of money on the account, say, 500€, to make sure it will not be drained by most transactions?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you can request this to specific more information including your balanace. According to information from eg. Caixa bank you would need this additional information to set up recurring transfers, applying for mortgages and other types of transactions: https://www.caixabank.es/particular/cuentas-bancarias/certificado-titularidad-p.html.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: But then, that's not what I'm asking about. I have meanwhile added an example of the document I am referring to; it really contains nothing beside the account number, identifying data of the owner, and the date when the account was opened.